# Improper token passed

Tags: python, token, discord, discord.py

I'm following a basic tutorial for a Python Discord bot on YouTube and my code is underneath. It says:

> discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

Before anyone asks, yes I have put in the bot token, not the id or secret.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:")

client.run("token is here")
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

Comment: Try regenerating the bot token.  Make sure that the copy/paste isn't adding any whitespace to the string.  Without looking at the token (which you shouldn't share), I don't see how anyone can help.

Comment: `client.run("token is here", bot=True)` or `client.run("token is here", bot=False)`

Comment: The error message said "Improper token has been passed." while your code has `client.run("token is here")`. Isn't that obvious ?!

Answer (score 19):

For me, my `bot.py` file looks like this:

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

and since I used env (environment) modules, I created a new file with an empty name and with the *.env* extension in the same path in a folder. The env file only has this line of code:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=DFHKJAhka7fdsKHJASDFk1jhaf5afd.HASDFafd23FHdfa_adfahHJKADF32W
```

So the problem for me was I was using brackets around the token code and after I removed it, it worked!

My code when it had brackets:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN={DFHKJAhka7fdsKHJASDFk1jhaf5afd.HASDFafd23FHdfa_adfahHJKADF32W}
```

Comment: I agree with @zabop. Assuming you're following the same example as me, you're instructed to replace the "placeholders" with actual values. You are not told that the placeholders include the curly brackets. Once the curly brackets are deleted, the problem is fixed.

Comment: Bizarrely, I couldn't get the example to work at all by bypassing the .env file. I just put the token in the script as a string. and it didn't like it as it had none of the string attributes or methods like strip().

Answer (score 15):

Make sure you grab the "Token" from the "Bot" page in the Discord development site, rather than the "Secret" from the "General Information" page.

I was having the same problem. My issue was solved by using the correct token from the Discord app page. I was using the "Secret" from the 'General Information' page (which generated the error in the original post for me) instead of the "Token" from the "Bot" page.

As sheneb said in the comment to this, this answer (probably) won't help the OP (since the question now says "Before anyone asks, yes I have put in the bot token, not the id or secret"). However, I found this question/page when searching for the answer, and my issue was solved with this information.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me, but it started working when I went to the developer page and refreshed the token. Then I just put the new token in the code and it worked!

Maybe the same will work for you...?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it to work by doing this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await message.channel.send(":cookie:")

bot.run("token is here")
```

I do this sometimes, but also, check to make sure you have fully created your bot by taking a look at the "bot" tab on your developer page.

I also made a fix for your message send line, your bot declaration and a removed the `discord.Client()` instance you never actually used.

Comment: Re *"You should be able to get it to work by doing this"*: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What is the theory of operation? Why would it work? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59558131/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await message.client.send(":cookie:")

client.run("TOKEN HERE. PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE ;)")
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60987988/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await message.client.send(":cookie:")

client.run("PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE")
```