# Error: "Improper token has been passed" discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Beginning to learn to write a simple Discord bot in Python. My bot's token is in a .env file but I'm getting the error `discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.`

Putting the token in `client.run(TOKEN_HERE)` doesn't work for me as it does with some people.

I'm using the token from the Bot page on the Discord Developer Portal not the Client Secret from the General Information page.

I'm using Visual Studio Code.

bot.py:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

.env:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=secret_token_here
```

Full error output:

```
Eds-MacBook-Pro:~ ed$ python3 /users/ed/documents/supremesauce/supremesauce.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/users/ed/documents/supremesauce/supremesauce.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 265, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Eds-MacBook-Pro:~ ed$
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you try printing the token locally to see if it's actually being passed, if it still persists refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602617/improper-token-passed).

Comment: Yeah I tried that it's actually being passed. I already referred to that thread but I was already doing everything and none of what they were saying fixed my issue.

Comment: Your token should look like this: `MjM4NDk0NzU2NTIxMzc3Nzky.CunGFQ.wUILz7z6HoJzVeq6pyHPmVgQgV4`. If that's the case, make sure it is a string and therefore is surrounded by quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

As some of the comments have said, make sure that your token has quotation marks around it. Beyond that, it might be worth trying regenerate a new token, and go from there.

I would once again make sure you are passing in a string.