# I'm getting "discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized". Nothing worked so far

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py, helper

This is what i've already tried:

1. Tried running code that has been untouched for months and i got the same error
2. I tried regenerating the token
3. I tried a different bot
4. I tried a bot from a different discord account
5. I tried to print the token and it worked all fine
6. I have tried changing my bot to public and a whole bunch of other discord bot settings
7. I have tried different ways of importing the token such as,

   ```
   Token = "Token"
   Client.run(Token)
   ```

   And a whole bunch of different ones
8. Tried changing from visual studio's to just normal python terminal

It just started happening out of nowhere, i was editing my new bot, ran it a couple of times to get the errors out of the code and then it worked and then closed it ran it again and it started giving me this so i find it pretty strange because it was so out of the blue. I have tried a lot that it said online already but nothing seemed to work. Please help, this has been going on for 4 days now and want it fixed cause then i can resume bot developing.

This is the huge error i'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 349, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 302, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Programming\Python\Discord bot\LastOneEverythingCombined\TEST.py", line 112, in <module>
    client.run('OTA0NjMxMzE2MzU0NTg4NzEz.YX-VkQ._B-EnQRE3IhWYl0psJA8UxZuI6s')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 631, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 610, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 573, in start
    await self.login(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 424, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 353, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001B4F30E1EA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001B4F30E1EA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001B4F30E1EA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 745, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I have no clue how to fix it and have tried everything on the web This is my code: in the spot of Token i have my token but ofcourse lets keep it hidden :)

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
Code....
client.run('Token')
```

Last time i put my entire code there and people got mad so i am now just putting the code i think might be necessary for this problem, if you need any other bits of code just reply with i need all the code to solve this error or more code and then the specific bit that you need or think might be in it

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: I am using python version 3.10.1 and discord.py version 1.7.3, sorry for the late respond. I forgot to check on here.

Comment: Check this pots. I think it can help you:
[Improper token passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602617/improper-token-passed)

Comment: I allready tried that before. Its not the wrong token. My Discord is TTSDEK#5147 i can screenshare it and maybe you can find the thing wrong in it. ill just use a new created bot so that the token doesnt matter

Comment: Ok. DM me on discord. I want to test some things with your token.
My discord: `Hazzu#0707`

Comment: Just added, btw it has nothing to do with token. On Heroku (A hosting platform) it runs perfectly so im really curious after why it is not working

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a .env to save your token check if you're not puting it in brackets

it will look like this

```
MyBotToken=iBUGUgUVUIByViBiuvYiUBiyViBiV
```

(it's not an actual token it's just an exemple)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem happened with me, i just kept on resetting bot token and using it.
but it did'nt solved the problem.

later i remembered that i have created a environment variable in my windows pc which was causing the issue changing it fixed my problem.