# Discord keeps raising 'improper token has been passed' even though it is correct

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to learn how to code a Discord bot, following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYJDKSah-Ww

When I tried to run it, though, it just keeps saying that it is an improper token. I have tried to refresh the IDE, reset the token key (***twice***) and even then, it still doesn't work (I used the same exact IDE, Intellij IDEA).

I have tried to look at three different questions here on S.O. (linked at the bottom), and they are not helpful, as they have answers of what I already tried to do.

## Code

### `main.py`

```py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord import Intents, Client, Message
from responses import get_response

load_dotenv()
TOKEN: str = os.getenv('TOKEN')
print(TOKEN)

intents: Intents = Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client: Client = Client(intents=intents)

async def send_message(message: Message, user_message: str) -> None:
    if not user_message:
        print('(Message empty; intents probably not setup correctly)')
        return

    if is_private := user_message[0] == '?':
        user_message = user_message[1:]

    try:
        response: str = get_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@client.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    print(f'{client.user} is now running on the treadmill!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message: Message) -> None:
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    username: str = str(message.author)
    user_message: str = message.content
    channel: str = str(message.channel)

    print(f'[{channel}] {username}: "{user_message}"')

    await send_message(message, user_message)


def main():
    client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### `responses.py`

```py
from random import choice, randint

def get_response(user_input: str) -> str:
    lowered: str = user_input.lower()

    if lowered == '':
        return 'Oh honey cakes, why are you so silent?'
    elif 'hello' in lowered:
        return 'Hey sweet cheeks ;)'
    else:
        return choice([
            'Hold up, HUH?'
            'What are you talking about honey?'
            '???'
        ])
```

## Questions

[#1] - [Improper token passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602617/improper-token-passed)

Comment: Just to confirm, you followed the exact instructions as given on https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/python/build-basic-discord-bot-python?

Comment: Yes, and it is pissing me off b/c I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: I ask, because your post shows a youtube link to a video by someone who isn't replit, so if their tutorial doesn't, you abandon it and go to the official one instead. If you followed the replit tutorial, and it doesn't work, then it's time to [report that to replit](https://ask.replit.com/c/support/57) with the details that will allow them to fix their documentation not just for you, but for everyone (while, of course, keeping this post open in case someone else knows what's going wrong here).

Comment: Is this really a *replit specific* issue though? If it's an improper token, it could mean a variety of things that have already been answered on this site.  @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Improper token passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602617/improper-token-passed)

Comment: @BlueRobin indeed, and starting over and following a tutorial by a reputable source may help someone figure out the problem all on their own, especially if that source is the hosting service they're using =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Oh true. That's also quicker than learning how that service works in its basic form to use transferrable skills elsewhere. I guess it's really just a tradeoff depending on how you look at it. One could learn the service's basic inner workings and then use that to fix their problem (example: it's linux or something & replit uses yarn I think for libs) or they just follow a quick tutorial